# macOS hide tabs in safari permanently with multiple tabs

Tags: macos, safari

Is there any script to permanently hide the tab bar in safari in macOS when I have multiple tabs open?

It is an extra vertical space I could use to display contents of the web page rather than an annoying tab bar. This is allowed in iOS and iPadOS 13 but not in macOS 10.14.5. Haven’t tried the 10.15.